# Java stack trace overlaps error message

Tags: java, docker

Debian Jessie and OpenJDK running on Windows Docker Toolbox, strange behavior from printStackTrace() on an Exception:

[image: error]

The Exception is a java.lang.NullPointerException, but somehow the stack trace is overwriting or overlapping the first line of the error message, making it difficult to debug. I added the red line to delineate the stack trace text. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the container or Java, it is actually a problem of the terminal emulation, I have seen this as well but did not yet find a solution.

Comment: If that is the problem then he needs to redirect standard output error  to a file.

Comment: Yes, just a terminal problem, need to do a log file.